# Missing type definitions for node.js http.incomingMessage

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm wondering why http.IncomingMessage.aborted is not defined in "@types/node": "^10.12.6". If I run the following code aborted works as expected. That is, if I kill the transaction aborted is true; otherwise it's false.

```
import * as http from 'http';

let server = http.createServer((req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse) =>
{   
    // pretend to do some processing...
    setTimeout(() => {        
        let aborted: boolean = (req as any)['aborted'];
        console.log(`response aborted ${aborted}`);
        res.end(`the end\n`);
    }, 2000);

}).listen(80);
```

Aborted has been available since v0.3.0 seems strange that it isn't defined.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The `aborted` [*event*](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_aborted) was added in v0.3.8 - the `aborted` [*field*](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_aborted) was added in v10.1.0, which is quite recent.

Therefore it's highly likely that [the type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts#L1255) just haven't been updated yet - I'd recommend submitting a pull request to add it, so that everyone else can benefit :)